# split a char array by finding a token char

Tags: c++, arrays, char, comparison, c-strings

I cannot figure out why this function won't work. 
I want to return a string what is trimmed from the char array passed into the function at the index where it finds an identifying char. Is there something obvious I'm missing? As it is, this only returns the first letter of the input char[]...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

string trim(char in[], char token){
char A[300];
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(in); i++){
  if(in[i] != token){
    A[i] = in[i];
  } else
    A[i] = '\0';
    break;
}

  return A;

}

int main()
{   char statement[] = {"weight of car is ?1 ton"};
    cout << trim(statement, '?') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you `break;` in the first iteration. Use a block to avoid it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

string trim(char in[], char token){
char A[300];
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(in); i++){
  if(in[i] != token){
    A[i] = in[i];
  } else {
    A[i] = '\0';
    break;
  }
}

  return A;

}

int main()
{   char statement[] = {"weight of car is ?1 ton"};
    cout << trim(statement, '?') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that calling `strlen` too many times isn't a good idea.

This should be better:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string trim(char in[], char token){
    char A[300];
    bool token_found = false;
    for(int i = 0; in[i] != '\0'; i++){
      if(in[i] != token){
        A[i] = in[i];
      } else {
        A[i] = '\0';
        token_found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (token_found) {
      return A;
    } else {
      return in;
    }

}

int main()
{   char statement[] = {"weight of car is ?1 ton"};
    cout << trim(statement, '?') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I am new to c++ and didn't realize you could put a condition comparing chars into a for loop. I will try that out.